# How to obtain the Jacobian from the returned data of the leastsq()?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am using frequently `scipy.optimize.leastsq()` for my Ph.D thesis however I have no idea how can I get the estimate of a jacobian from the data that `leastsq()` returns. I need to know the estimate of a jacobian that is used in minimization to compare with the finite difference approximation at minimum.

Does anyone has a formula how to get it?

This can be a bit tricky when you check how for e.g. a covariance matrix is calculated inside `leastsq()`

Comment: The Jacobian leastsq uses is done by finite foward difference, so you won't win much.

Comment: Yes, but in my case the step in forward difference is very important. So if the leastsq is using too small value then the jacobian may be zero because of the rounding errors. So I need to compare the jacobians calculated by my own with the ones from leastsq.

Comment: Are the terms in your matrix observed data with limited precision or from formulas so you could in principle compute them to as much precision as you liked?

Comment: They are computed from "numerical formulas" however I cannot calculate them with given precision. This is because they come from a really complicated problem and there is a lot of "computational noise" in them. Because of this I know that changing a paramer by, let's say 0.001 will make nonsense and give random derivative, but change by 1.0 will be allright and derivative will be ok. This is why I need to see the jacobian, and better the step for each parameter that leastsq() is using.

Comment: FYI: The size of steps used by the finite forward difference estimation of the Jacobian in `scipy.optimize.leastsq` is controlled by the `epsfcn` keyword argument. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.leastsq.html#scipy.optimize.leastsq  Alternately, you could always supply your own function to calculate the Jacobian using a similar finite-difference method.

Comment: The code of lmdif is not very difficult to read, if you really want you jacoboian.

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer is that nobody ever managed to recover the Jacobian from optimize.leastsq.

latest threat on this http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-user/2011-August/030320.html

From some examples of the covariance matrix returned by leastsq, I think there are many cases where the precision with default settings is not very high.

To check how good it is, you can compare the returned covariance matrix with the outer product of your Jacobian.

Comment: Indeed, this is a very good answer. The above comment are right about the fact that leastsq() uses a finite difference approximation of jacobian with a step determined by epsfcn parameter. This can be simply checked by looking at arguments passed to to the minimized function. However the approx. of covariance matrix can be different from the one that you can obtain by calculating the jacobian by your own in minimum using same step in finite differences. This may be because very often np.dot(jacobian.T, jacobian) becomes ill-defined and hance its inverse.

Comment: Why not using the `autograd` package to compute the Jacobian?